# What should I watch first? The Last: Naruto the movie or Sasuke's story sunrise arc?

Tags: naruto

The anime story finished back in October. A few filler then followed the new sunrise arc in Sasuke's story, which started where Sasuke goes on his own adventure.

My question is, should I watch the last movie first or does Sasuke's story arc come first?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in this answer, [How much time has passed between the final fight and Sasuke Shinden (anime)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/37849/how-much-time-has-passed-between-the-final-fight-and-sasuke-shinden-anime/37852#37852)

The full timeline is linked in the Reddit Thread: [Naruto timeline](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/33zfy3/a_guide_to_the_naruto_light_novels_naruto_gaiden/)
The relevant part is:

However, these events are being produced in a non chronological manner and hence the confusion. Naruto: The Last was aired before the end of 4th Ninja War. Sasuke Shinden has been adapted before other works, such as Shikamaru Shinden which is now airing.

Thus there is no "recommended order" for watching the series. The stories are not that reliant on each other and you can watch the movies/episodes as you want (After episode 479).

To answer the real question, **The events of Naruto: The Last take place before Sasuke Shinden: Book of Sunrise.**

Personally, I wait for a few episodes to pile up and then watch them in their chronological order.

[image: Official Timeline]
[image: Sasuke Shinden]

Answer (score 0):

Sasuke's arc comes first. I would recommend you to first finish that.